# Mongodb aggregation sort with lookup on large collations

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have performance issue with look up and sort in aggregation.

Before I needed the sort, I did limit and then lookup and it was fast but now because of the sort, I need to put the lookup first and this increase the query by 30 sec.

Old query :

```js
query.push({$skip: start});
query.push({$limit: length});
query.push({
      $lookup: {
          from: "campaigns",
          localField: "campaign_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "campaign"
      }
  });
```

new query :

```js
query.push({
    $lookup: {
        from: "campaigns",
        localField: "campaign_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "campaign"
    }
});

query.push({$sort: {"campaign.name": order.dir === 'asc' ? 1 : -1}});
query.push({$skip: start});
query.push({$limit: length});
```

Also because the campaign field coming from the lookup, I can't index it.

What is the best approach for scenario that you need sort from lookup?

Comment: _id will already be indexed, so it will make use of the index. It seems sort is on the current collection, not based on the looked-up value. So, what is the problem doing sort, skip, limit first?

Comment: @RaR the sort was a variable. i fixed it